# boto3 says table is non-existent but I can query it in the AWS CLI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, aws-cli

I'm trying to get a table description using boto3 and python using the following snippet:

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-2', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")

response = dynamodb.describe_table(
    TableName='bars'
)

print(response)
```

but I keep getting this error:

> botocore.errorfactory.ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the DescribeTable operation: Cannot do operations on a non-existent table

But I'm able to query it in the AWS CLI when I run this command:

```
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name bars
```

Is something borked with my boto3 setup? Obviously my aws config file is fine because I can access the table using the cli.

Comment: did you exclude the part of your code where you connect to `boto3` with your credentials?

Comment: Why are you setting the `endpoint_url` and the `region_name`, surely it is one or the other - either you are running it locally (Developer) or you are trying to connect to the `region` (Service). I'm assuming the `aws` cli is configured to go to the same region.

Comment: Are you connecting to [DynamoDB Local](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html) or the 'real' DynamoDB hosted on AWS? If the latter, then remove the `endpoint_url`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein that was it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `endpoint_url()`.

This is useful when connecting to [DynamoDB Local](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html) but is not necessary when connecting to the 'live' Amazon DynamoDB service.

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) will use the live service by default.